# Ag-grid Master detail collapse fails when destoying the detail grid

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, ag-grid-react

I'm working on a Node/React javascript app. I've configured ag-grid to display a master grid and then a detail grid per each row as per the documentation. Both grids display correctly, but upon collapsing the rowGroup (clicking on the agGroupCellRenderer of an row displaying a detail grid) the destroy process for the detail grid is stopped by an exception saying "refreshEvent is not a function". This leaves the master grid truncated and in rendering state, so that no api methods may be called without throwing further exceptions.

I have tried destroying the detail grid calling event.node.detailNode.detailGridInfo.api.destoy(); on onRowGroupOpened but the problem seem to happen before getting there.

Here is some code where I replace the agGroupCellRenderer with my own implementation. The exception is the same with either implementation:

```
        this.chartButtonCellRenderer = params => {

            var display = `<br /><a href="#">
<span style="color:#CCCCCC;font-size:16px"><i class="fas fa-chart-bar" /></span ></a>`;
            return display;
        };
        this.currencyFormatter = params => {
            return '$' + this.formatNumber(params.value);
        };
        this.formatNumber = number => {
            return number.toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, '$1,');
        };

        this.detailCellRendererParams = {
            // provide detail grid options
            detailGridOptions: {
                columnDefs: [
                    {
                        headerName: 'date',
                        chartDataType: 'category',
                        field: 'date'
                    },
                    {
                        headerName: 'SKU',
                        field: 'sku'
                    },
                    {
                        headerName: 'Name',
                        field: 'name'
                    },
                    {
                        headerName: 'Tier',
                        chartDataType: 'series',
                        field: 'tier'
                    },
                    {
                        headerName: 'Price',
                        chartDataType: 'series',
                        field: 'price'
                    },
                    {
                        headerName: 'Likes',
                        chartDataType: 'series',
                        field: 'likes'
                    }
                ]
            },

            // extract and supply row data for detail
            getDetailRowData: function(params) {
                params.successCallback(params.data.historicRecords);
            }
        };
        this.state = {
            errormsg: [],
            successmsg: [],
            modules: [ClientSideRowModelModule, MasterDetailModule, MenuModule, ColumnsToolPanelModule],
            columnDefs: [
                {
                    colId: 'chart',
                    headerName: '',
                    field: 'sku',
                    cellRenderer: this.chartButtonCellRenderer,
                    //cellRenderer: 'agGroupCellRenderer',
                    //showGroup: false,
                    width: 50
                },
                {
                    headerName: 'Image',
                    field: 'image',
                    cellRenderer: this.imageCellRenderer,
                    width: 75
                },
                {
                    headerName: 'Name',
                    field: 'name',
                    chartDataType: 'category',
                    cellRenderer: this.titleCellRenderer
                },
                {
                    headerName: 'Tier',
                    chartDataType: 'series',
                    field: 'tier'
                },
                {
                    headerName: 'Price',
                    chartDataType: 'series',
                    field: 'price',
                    valueFormatter: this.currencyFormatter
                },
                {
                    headerName: 'Likes',
                    chartDataType: 'series',
                    field: 'likes'
                }
            ],
            overlayLoadingTemplate:
                '<span class="ag-overlay-loading-center">Please wait while product data loads</span>',
            enableCharts: true,
            masterDetail: true,
            defaultColDef: {
                editable: false,
                sortable: true,
                flex: 0,
                minWidth: 20,
                autoHeight: true,
                filter: true,
                resizable: true
            },
            detailCellRendererParams: this.detailCellRendererParams,
            rowData: []
        };
    }

    onCellClicked(event) {
        console.log('A cell was clicked', event.value, event.colDef, event.column);

        event.node.setExpanded(!event.node.expanded);
    }

onRowGroupOpened = event => {
        var detailGridApi = event.node.detailNode.detailGridInfo.api;
        if (event.node.expanded) {
            console.log('Row group opened:', event);
            var title = event.data.title;
            var start = 0;
            var end = event.data.historicRecords.length - 1;

            this.renderDetailChart(start, end, title, detailGridApi);
        } else {
            //on collapse

            console.log('Row group collapsed:', event);

            if (this.mainChart) {
                this.mainChart = this.mainChart.destroyChart();
                this.mainChart = null;
            }

            var chartparams = this.configureChart(0, 10, 'line', 'Main', ['salesrank', 'price', 'reviews']);
            this.mainChart = event.api.createRangeChart(chartparams);
        }
    };
```

Here is the stack trace:

```
ag-grid-enterprise.cjs.js:4160 Uncaught TypeError: refreshEvent is not a function
    at ag-grid-enterprise.cjs.js:4160
    at ag-grid-community.cjs.js:12228
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at RowGroupDropZonePanel.BeanStub.destroy (ag-grid-community.cjs.js:12227)
    at RowGroupDropZonePanel.Component.destroy (ag-grid-community.cjs.js:12685)
    at RowGroupDropZonePanel.BaseDropZonePanel.destroy (ag-grid-enterprise.cjs.js:4141)
    at ag-grid-enterprise.cjs.js:4843
    at ag-grid-community.cjs.js:12228
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at GridHeaderDropZones.BeanStub.destroy (ag-grid-community.cjs.js:12227)
    at GridHeaderDropZones.Component.destroy (ag-grid-community.cjs.js:12685)
    at ag-grid-community.cjs.js:12689
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at GridCore.Component.destroy (ag-grid-community.cjs.js:12687)
    at GridCore.destroy (ag-grid-community.cjs.js:35948)
    at GridApi.destroy (ag-grid-community.cjs.js:34185)
    at ag-grid-enterprise.cjs.js:40655
    at ag-grid-community.cjs.js:12228
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at DetailCellRenderer.BeanStub.destroy (ag-grid-community.cjs.js:12227)
    at DetailCellRenderer.Component.destroy (ag-grid-community.cjs.js:12685)
    at DetailRowCompCache.destroyFullWidthRow (ag-grid-community.cjs.js:44310)
    at DetailRowCompCache.addOrDestroy (ag-grid-community.cjs.js:44241)
    at RowComp.destroyFullWidthComponents (ag-grid-community.cjs.js:24433)
    at RowComp.destroy (ag-grid-community.cjs.js:25331)
    at ag-grid-community.cjs.js:26470
    at ag-grid-community.cjs.js:1074
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Function.Utils.iterateObject (ag-grid-community.cjs.js:1073)
    at RowRenderer.destroyRowComps (ag-grid-community.cjs.js:26464)
    at RowRenderer.redraw (ag-grid-community.cjs.js:26347)
    at RowRenderer.redrawAfterModelUpdate (ag-grid-community.cjs.js:25964)
    at RowRenderer.onModelUpdated (ag-grid-community.cjs.js:25890)
    at RowRenderer.onPageLoaded (ag-grid-community.cjs.js:25823)
    at ag-grid-community.cjs.js:4229
    at Set.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at processEventListeners (ag-grid-community.cjs.js:4223)
    at EventService.dispatchToListeners (ag-grid-community.cjs.js:4236)
    at EventService.dispatchEvent (ag-grid-community.cjs.js:4207)
    at PaginationProxy.onModelUpdated (ag-grid-community.cjs.js:38239)
    at ag-grid-community.cjs.js:4229
    at Set.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at processEventListeners (ag-grid-community.cjs.js:4223)
    at EventService.dispatchToListeners (ag-grid-community.cjs.js:4236)
    at EventService.dispatchEvent (ag-grid-community.cjs.js:4207)
    at ClientSideRowModel.refreshModel (ag-grid-community.cjs.js:47767)
    at ClientSideRowModel.onRowGroupOpened (ag-grid-community.cjs.js:47642)
    at ag-grid-community.cjs.js:4229
    at Set.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at processEventListeners (ag-grid-community.cjs.js:4223)

(anonymous) @   ag-grid-enterprise.cjs.js:4160
(anonymous) @   ag-grid-community.cjs.js:12228
BeanStub.destroy    @   ag-grid-community.cjs.js:12227
Component.destroy   @   ag-grid-community.cjs.js:12685
BaseDropZonePanel.destroy   @   ag-grid-enterprise.cjs.js:4141
(anonymous) @   ag-grid-enterprise.cjs.js:4843
(anonymous) @   ag-grid-community.cjs.js:12228
BeanStub.destroy    @   ag-grid-community.cjs.js:12227
Component.destroy   @   ag-grid-community.cjs.js:12685
(anonymous) @   ag-grid-community.cjs.js:12689
Component.destroy   @   ag-grid-community.cjs.js:12687
GridCore.destroy    @   ag-grid-community.cjs.js:35948
GridApi.destroy @   ag-grid-community.cjs.js:34185
(anonymous) @   ag-grid-enterprise.cjs.js:40655
(anonymous) @   ag-grid-community.cjs.js:12228
BeanStub.destroy    @   ag-grid-community.cjs.js:12227
Component.destroy   @   ag-grid-community.cjs.js:12685
DetailRowCompCache.destroyFullWidthRow  @   ag-grid-community.cjs.js:44310
DetailRowCompCache.addOrDestroy @   ag-grid-community.cjs.js:44241
RowComp.destroyFullWidthComponents  @   ag-grid-community.cjs.js:24433
RowComp.destroy @   ag-grid-community.cjs.js:25331
(anonymous) @   ag-grid-community.cjs.js:26470
(anonymous) @   ag-grid-community.cjs.js:1074
Utils.iterateObject @   ag-grid-community.cjs.js:1073
RowRenderer.destroyRowComps @   ag-grid-community.cjs.js:26464
RowRenderer.redraw  @   ag-grid-community.cjs.js:26347
RowRenderer.redrawAfterModelUpdate  @   ag-grid-community.cjs.js:25964
RowRenderer.onModelUpdated  @   ag-grid-community.cjs.js:25890
RowRenderer.onPageLoaded    @   ag-grid-community.cjs.js:25823
(anonymous) @   ag-grid-community.cjs.js:4229
processEventListeners   @   ag-grid-community.cjs.js:4223
EventService.dispatchToListeners    @   ag-grid-community.cjs.js:4236
EventService.dispatchEvent  @   ag-grid-community.cjs.js:4207
PaginationProxy.onModelUpdated  @   ag-grid-community.cjs.js:38239
(anonymous) @   ag-grid-community.cjs.js:4229
processEventListeners   @   ag-grid-community.cjs.js:4223
EventService.dispatchToListeners    @   ag-grid-community.cjs.js:4236
EventService.dispatchEvent  @   ag-grid-community.cjs.js:4207
ClientSideRowModel.refreshModel @   ag-grid-community.cjs.js:47767
ClientSideRowModel.onRowGroupOpened @   ag-grid-community.cjs.js:47642
(anonymous) @   ag-grid-community.cjs.js:4229
processEventListeners   @   ag-grid-community.cjs.js:4223
EventService.dispatchToListeners    @   ag-grid-community.cjs.js:4235
EventService.dispatchEvent  @   ag-grid-community.cjs.js:4207
RowNode.setExpanded @   ag-grid-community.cjs.js:15209
onCellClicked   @   Dashboard.js:163
GridOptionsWrapper.globalEventHandler   @   ag-grid-community.cjs.js:11776
(anonymous) @   ag-grid-community.cjs.js:4241
(anonymous) @   ag-grid-community.cjs.js:4280
EventService.flushAsyncQueue    @   ag-grid-community.cjs.js:4279
setTimeout (async)      
EventService.dispatchAsync  @   ag-grid-community.cjs.js:4262
(anonymous) @   ag-grid-community.cjs.js:4240
EventService.dispatchToListeners    @   ag-grid-community.cjs.js:4238
EventService.dispatchEvent  @   ag-grid-community.cjs.js:4206
FocusController.onCellFocused   @   ag-grid-community.cjs.js:36925
FocusController.setFocusedCell  @   ag-grid-community.cjs.js:36854
CellComp.focusCell  @   ag-grid-community.cjs.js:22988
CellComp.onMouseDown    @   ag-grid-community.cjs.js:23184
CellComp.onMouseEvent   @   ag-grid-community.cjs.js:22635
GridPanel.processMouseEvent @   ag-grid-community.cjs.js:32223
```

Comment: Hey Juan, kindly try to explain your question in more detail. The output is a good hint, but a code example would help, to find a working solution. This will motivate others to help you.

Comment: Thanks Pauloco, the issue happens on a mouse click event on a ag-grid supplied cell renderer, so I don't know what code of mine could help here or even which is relevant to this issue. I'll try to add the config for the grid.

Comment: Well, you have some code, where you are using the ag-grid. I'm not an expert on that particular problem, but sometimes the error lies in how things are called, interaction with other elements etc. So it would just help to see your code in question! Of course if the error lies in the ag-grid itself, you are right, your code won't help. But let's assume that is not the case :)

Comment: Added code as requested.

Comment: Hey Juan, trying to find the solution together: have you ever set the `suppressRefresh: true`? Does this change anything? Even if that is not what you want, it could help narrow down to problem. I found that in this example: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-master-detail/#changing-data-refresh

Comment: Thanks, I added the supressRefresh but it did not change the error.

Answer (score 0):

Happy to report this issue got solved by updating ag-grid using npm:

```
npm update ag-grid-community
npm update ag-grid-enterprise
```